# Prove a set is homeomorphic to the n-disc

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $S^{n-1}\times[0,1]/S^{n-1}\times\{0\}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb D^n$. I understand how this works for small n but I'm having trouble constructing a function so I can prove they're homeomorphic. Or is there a simpler way? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $S^1\times[0,1]$ is easily embedded in $\Bbb R^2$ as the closed annulus between $x^2+y^2=\frac14$ and $x^2+y^2=1$, say. Now shrink the inner boundary radially to the origin, and you’ve mapped $\big(S^1\times[0,1]\big)/\big(S^1\times\{0\}\big)$ to $\Bbb D^2$. That is, if $\frac12\le r\le 1$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, map $\langle r,\theta\rangle$ to $\left\langle 2r-1,\theta\right\rangle$.

This idea generalizes easily to higher dimensions: $\theta$ is replaced by a point of $S^{n-1}$, and $r$ remains a radial distance from the origin. You can still visualize this when $n=3$ to get the general idea.

Comment: so I replace $r$ with the $d(x,y)$ where $y$ is the origin? I'm not exactly sure how to replace $\theta$ with an element of $S^{n-1}$

Comment: @user66339: You don’t have to do it explicitly. It now occurs to me that you can even perform my two steps simultaneously: for $0\le r\le 1$ embed $S^{n-1}\times\{r\}$ into $\Bbb R^n$ as the points $\langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ such that $x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2=r^2$. For $r=1$ that’s just the usual embedding of $S^{n-1}$ into $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Hi, Is $\big(S^1\times[0,1]\big)$ a cylinder? And what is $\big(S^1\times\{0\}\big)$ exactly and what is $\big(S^1\times[0,1]\big)/\big(S^1\times\{0\}\big)$? I am new to this. A short reply would be very helpful, thanks. I know when you take the quotient you identify certain points but i cant really picture it because i am unsure what those three spaces are.

Comment: @JKnecht: Yes, $S^1\times[0,1]$ is a cylinder of height $1$. $S^1\times\{0\}$ is the circle that forms its base. The quotient identifies this base circle to a single point. Imagine deforming the cylinder to an ice cream cone: the base of the cylinder gets smaller and smaller until it collapses to a point.

Comment: If $X$ be the union of axes given by $xy = 0$ in $R^2$. Is it homeomorphic to a line, a circle, a parabola or the rectangular hyperbola $xy = 1$  @Brian M.Scott   Can u plzz give me some hint for this problem..?